# Line chart in Elastic Search Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, charts, kibana

I have the following json fields in my file -

```
message:
{"File":"File1","Hour":"22","Count":"493"}
{"File":"File1","Hour":"23","Count":"32"}
{"File":"File3","Hour":"1","Count":"45"}
```

I am trying to plot a line chart with “Hour” in x axis and “Count” in y axis. Then for each File, I would like to see the count for every hour.

In the buckets field, we have option only to set the x axis. Y axis is by default set to “Count”. Just started using Kibana, not sure how to do the settings to plot the line chart. Any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: how to plot a line with “Hour” in x axis and “Count” in y axis.

First, I modified your data a bit. I removed quotes from "Hour" and "Count" to make them numbers (instead of strings). I also added a timestamp, because Kibana requires it. Here is how I created your data:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test-file/DataPoint/AVZa2HjWew5y36MUYXXL' -d '{"File":"File1","Hour":22,"Count":493, "@timestamp" : "2016-08-29T15:16:12"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test-file/DataPoint/AVZa2HjWew5y36MUYXXD' -d '{"File":"File1","Hour":23,"Count":32, "@timestamp" : "2016-08-29T15:16:12"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test-file/DataPoint/AVZa2HjWew5y36MUYXXB' -d '{"File":"File3","Hour":1,"Count":45, "@timestamp" : "2016-08-29T15:16:12"}'
```

For Y axis, I used `Max` of "Count". For Y axis, I used `Terms` of "Hours". Here is an image showing how I did it:

[image]